# javaScript: Split one function into two

Tags: javascript

I have the following working function (the lower part of it is not shown):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function plan_click(clicked_id){
    let var_plan;
    let var_sgldbl;
    var_sgldbl = 'sgl';
    var_plan = clicked_id;
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "green";

/* new code*/

    let var_tab01;
    switch (var_plan) {
    case '101':
        var_tab01 = 201;
        document.getElementById(var_tab01).style.background = "green";
        break;



}}
</script>
```

I want the function to be split into two functions at the /*new code*/ - in separate scripts as the new "tabeller" function might be placed in a js.-file. The "tabeller"-function should be called from the plan_click-function and receive the actual values from the variables: var_plan and var_sgldbl.

Which code should be inserted to make the split effective?

Comment: For what you're doing, consider adding a class of like "select" or something and putting the styling in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the code out to another function. `var_plan` should be a parameter, while `var_tab01` can be the return value.

```
function plan_click(clicked_id) {
  let var_plan;
  let var_sgldbl;
  var_sgldbl = 'sgl';
  var_plan = clicked_id;
  document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.background = "green";

  let var_tab01 = tabeler(var_plan);
  ...
}

function tabeler(var_plan)
  let var_tab01;
  switch (var_plan) {
    case '101':
      var_tab01 = 201;
      document.getElementById(var_tab01).style.background = "green";
      break;
    ...
  }
  return var_tab01;
}
```

Comment: Looks okay, but [it's a bad practice in JavaScript to reassign function arguments](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/10/javascript-don-t-reassign-your-function-arguments).

Comment: @StackSlave Since most functions don't use `arguments` (and the introduction of default values and `...` in ES6 make it less necessary) I consider that not very persuasive.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood the original code, and `var_tab01` doesn't need to be a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, OP probably doesn't know how to use function `arguments`. I just like to have that option. I also, like to use both kinds of functions. `this`!!!